# Why cannot access to variable inside function that assigned jquery object

Tags: javascript

I cannot access `button` or `container` variable inside the functions. What's the problem?

```
var Site = {
    init: function () {
        $(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button").click(function () {
            Site.Navigation.toggle();
            return false;
        });
    },
    Navigation: {
        container: $(".site .head .nav-bar .navigation"),
        button: $(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button"),
        toggle: function () {
            if (this.button.hasClass("active")) {
                this.hide();
            }
            else {
                this.show();
            }
        },
        show: function () {
            this.button.addClass("active");
            this.container.slideDown();
            return false;
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.button.removeClass("active");
            this.container.slideUp();
            return false;
        }
        //another stuff
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Site.init();
});
```

Comment: How are you calling `toggle`?

Comment: Is it possible that your jQuery selectors are not returning any elements? Can we see some html?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ec2Y6/1

Comment: @Austen when I call function directly from jquery object, It works:  e.g. `$(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button").addClass("active")`.

Comment: Check out kalley's fiddle. If you can't get it working using that, then bfavaretto is probably right and there is an issue with your script placement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure, but I believe what's happening is that your selectors are not matching any elements, because they're called before the elements are added to the DOM. I mean these:

```
container: $(".site .head .nav-bar .navigation"),
button: $(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button"),
```

Try moving your whole JavaScript to the end of the body (right before `</body>`).

Another possible solution is to only populate those properties from `Site.init` (currently, they're populated immediately when the object literal is declared:

```
var Site = {
    init: function () {

        this.Navigation.container = $(".site .head .nav-bar .navigation");
        this.Navigation.button = $(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button");

        $(".site .head .nav-bar .nav-button").click(function () {
            Site.Navigation.toggle();
            return false;
        });
    },
    Navigation: {
        container: null,
        button: null,
        toggle: function () {
            if (this.button.hasClass("active")) {
                this.hide();
            }
            else {
                this.show();
            }
        },
        show: function () {
            this.button.addClass("active");
            this.container.slideDown();
            return false;
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.button.removeClass("active");
            this.container.slideUp();
            return false;
        }
        //another stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: exactly. Why this happen? I run my init function after ready `$(document).ready(function () { Site.init();`

Comment: That code runs before `Site.init`. The `Navigation` object is created immediately when the object literal is declared, and the values of `container` and `button` are already defined (as empty jQuery objects) when `init` runs. You can move that logic to `init`, e.g., `this.Navigation.container = ...`)

Comment: @Sahar, Don't do this, it's a very bad practice to put this kind of module definition code inside `$(document).ready`. Use the approach I suggested instead. What's happening is that the values are assigned to `container` and `button` way before `Site.init` is called, since the assignments are happening as soon as the object gets created.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your elements probably don't exist yet when your object is defined, since the code isin't running after the DOM is ready.

You could modify your `Site.init` function to accept these element references as argument however.

```
   init: function (container, button) {
        var nav = this.Navigation;

        nav.container = container;
        nav.button = button;
    }
```

Then pass in the elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Site.init(/*containerEl*/, /*buttonEl*/);
});
```

Comment: Upvoted. I added another init function for `Navigation` to do something like that.